# get files in directory filtered by specific extension jsp

Tags: html, jsp, web, directory, filelist

I have this code for listing all files in specific folder and It works properly

```
<% 
        String file = application.getRealPath("files/"); 

        File f = new File(file);
        String [] fileNames = f.list();
        File [] fileObjects= f.listFiles();
    %>
    <form action="NewFile.jsp" method="get" data-ajax="false">

    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < fileObjects.length; i++) {
            if(!fileObjects[i].isDirectory()){
    %>


    <label>
    <input data-iconpos="right" type="radio"  data-mini="true" name="loadfile" id="radio-choice-0a" value='<%=fileNames[i]%>'><%=fileNames[i] %>
</label>
     <% 
            }
        }
    %>
```

What I want is to print only those files that have .Owl extension, can someone tell me the solution, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if(!fileObjects[i].isDirectory()){
```

to

```
if(!fileObjects[i].isDirectory() && 
    fileObjects[i].getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".owl")){
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working it gives me error in .endsWith (); any idea?

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "it gives me error".  What exactly is the error?

Comment: In fact, I can think of one more improvement which is to make the comparison case-insensitve.  See my final edit above.